# How to speed up the class scan via Reflection API in Java?

Tags: java, reflection

I use `org.reflections` library to scan ClassPath and get classes. Here is my code:

```
Reflections ref = new Reflections();
Set<Class<? extends Service>> classes = new HashSet<>();
for (Class<? extends Service> subType : ref.getSubTypesOf(Service.class)) {
    if (!Modifier.isAbstract(subType.getModifiers())) {
        classes.add(subType);
    }
}
```

But I faced a problem. It takes too much time. At the same time I can not set a package

```
new Reflections("my.pack");
```

because I want to save an ability to add Service classes in the future. How can I accelerate this process? Is it possible to exclude `rt.jar` packs?

Comment: How long does it take? And how many times are you running this, just once I assume?

Comment: You can have Reflections scan at [compile time](https://code.google.com/p/reflections/) and store this information. This will obviously not work if you classpath changes between compile time and run time.

Comment: @weston 40 seconds (2 minutes in debug).

Comment: You can't set your package, but have you tried excluding `java` package?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`FilterBuilder`](http://reflections.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/reflections/javadoc/apidocs/org/reflections/util/FilterBuilder.html) to exclude `java` root package at least.

And it may help to specify [`SubTypesScanner`](http://reflections.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/reflections/javadoc/apidocs/index.html?org/reflections/util/ClasspathHelper.html) as that's what you're doing.

```
Reflections ref = new Reflections(new SubTypesScanner(),
                                  new FilterBuilder().excludePackage("java"));
```

Comment: It still takes too much time.

Comment: But better at all? Might be on right track, there's more filters you could do.

Comment: A little better, yeap.

Comment: Well how long? we know 40 seconds before. We are people of science, we like numbers not vague concepts like "too long" and "little better" :p

Comment: 27 seconds approximately

Comment: Yes that's really long. I just tried here and without my suggestions took 2.9s and with took 2.3s

Comment: As you've ticked it, did you find a better filter in the end?

Comment: No, I didn't find a better filter. Anyway, it's not the best solution, but I added a property file in which I specify packages.